# Determine timezone based on location using Here APIs

Tags: here-api

I want to get get the timezone of a location (lat/long) using the here REST APIs.  I know there is a Google timezone API to do this, but I couldn't see any timezone information in any "Reverse Geocoding" API responses for the here REST APIs.

Answer (score 2):

For reverse geocoding you need to add additional parameter `locationattributes=tz` to the request. Example request:

```
https://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json
?prox=50.112,8.683,100
&mode=retrieveAddresses
&app_id=xxx
&app_code=yyy
&gen=9
&locationattributes=tz
```

You can find a full description of available input parameters by link: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html

Comment: Hmm. I'd need the DST independent tz scheme like "Europe/Berlin". The DST dependent tz scheme is returned in adminInfo: "TimeZoneOffset": "UTC+02:00"